# no sound in a push notification on Android(Ionic capacitor)

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I have a problem when i implemented a plugin PushNotification in capacitor, the problem is that when te phone receive a push notification don´t make any sound.
This is my code.

```
PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived',
  (notification: PushNotification) => {
    console.log('Push received: ',JSON.stringify(notification));

  }
```

this is the settings in capacitor.config.json

```
"PushNotifications": {
  "presentationOptions": ["badge", "sound", "alert"]
}
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the payload sent to your device?

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: I also have the same problem

Comment: if I print the notification I get a "{"id":"0:1654057387418274%1daf70eb1daf70eb","data":{},"title":"test 4","body":"test 4"}"

Answer (score 0):

show me the created the Notification channel Details. 
 Then don't test in Redmi or mi Phones.

```
addListenersForNotifications = async () => {
   await PushNotifications.addListener('registration', 'registration Name');
await PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', 'error');
await PushNotifications.createChannel({
  id: 'fcm_default_channel',
  name: 'app name',
  description: 'Show the notification if the app is open on your device',
  importance: 5,
  visibility: 1,
  lights: true,
  vibration: true,
});
await PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', this.pushNotificationReceived);
await PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed', this.pushNotificationActionPerformed);
```

};